# Pretty simple SQL query using another query

Tags: sql

I need to select all IDs from one table with columns `ID` and `X`,  `WHERE X = 'Y'`. For each of those `ID`s, I need to look up some stuff in a different table:

If the `ID` does not exist, it gets no row in the final result.

If the `ID` does exist, I want to do some logic to figure out if it gets a row. For simplicity, assume that the logic is: if column `Q > 0`.

So the final result is simply a column of `ID`s, throwing out some because they are disqualified for one of two reasons as above.

thanks.

Comment: edit your question's format. use the `code` and `blockquote` editor options and put some line breakers please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `JOIN`s are made for.

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.ID = table2.table1_ID
    AND table2.Q > 0;
```

This will select all records in table1 (which have IDs) and then remove any records that do not have a matching record in table2 or do not have a Q > 0.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right this might be what you are looking for:

```
select id from your_table
where X = 'Y'
and id in (select id from other_table where Q > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

`SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE table1.id IN (SELECT q FROM table2 WHERE table2.q > 0) AND table1.x='y'`

SQL will check to see if the results from the outermost query are in the subquery (the part in parentheses) and won't return anything if they aren't.